# I am sending time as 00:00:00 but it is appending Current Time

Tags: java, sql, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format

I am using `Joda DateTime` and I am passing `start_date=08-07-2017T00:00:00Z` in Request, but the current date is `2017-07-07T4:30:00Z`. But it is appending current time for future date.

Is there any particular reason for this?

I'm trying to convert to this format:

```
startDate.getSqlDate().toString() + "T" 
          + startDate.getSimpleDate(SystemConstants.TIME_FORMAT_HH_MM_SS)

public static final String TIME_FORMAT_HH_MM_SS = "HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That timestamp format is not ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: What's the type of `startDate`? What String is resulted from `startDate.getSqlDate().toString()+"T"+startDate.getSimpleDate(SystemConstants.TIME_FORMAT_HH_MM_SS)`? How are you doing the conversion?

Comment: Please put up a [mcve]. You are *describing* what you are doing. That doesnt really help much